# I can't find any snap app after I update the system

Tags: snap

There is nothing in the list, what is going on?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Canonical doesn't want users to discover snaps this way anymore.

```
snap find
```

now returns this error:

```
error: cannot list snaps: empty query
```

According to Canonical’s John Lenton:

> “snap find” without arguments has not shown “all available snaps” in quite a while; it would show 100 arbitrary snaps. That is expensive and never what the user wanted, so in 2.11 we stopped doing that.
>
> Having ‘snap find’ return all snap packages is expensive, both on server resources (to get, collate and serialise everything), network bandwidth (to transmit the dump), and client resources (to display all of that). It would also force us to support pagination of the store queries in snapd, and of snapd responses.

#### Workaround

```
snap find .
```

Explanation:

You need to pass an argument to the `snap find` command. The argument can be either the name of a snap package or a regular expression to return a list of packages matching the regular expression as in the above example command.

Comment: I see. By the way, if there are some problems with the snap Apps, whom should I reply to? The App developer or Ubuntu?

Comment: Canonical employees Daniel Holbach (dholbach) and David Planella (David Planella) are snap developers and two of the top answerers for Ask Ubuntu questions with the snap tag.

Comment: Note that this does not reference the related bug link, and it may be prudent to if people want to track the progress of any type of "fix" for the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1609368